# Swift and Parse - Message app, cannot display username within Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, option-type

I have some issue to display the 'author's username of each posts in my TableViewController.

It actually display the current user's username for all display posts, how to display each poster's username ?

I'm using Xcode 6.3 and Parse.com API.
The timeLabel is displayed correctly, but the userLabel display the current user who is logged in instead of the author of the post.

If I logged out and login with a different username all the userLabel change to the new user. The debug console display `Optional("theNameOfTheCurrentUser")` as many times as there are posts displayed.

Parse host 2 DB one for users (User) and one for posts (Poemes), there is a pointer in Poemes table to the specific user.

I update to Xcode 6.3 lately and had an error on `var findLover:PFQuery = PFUser.query()`

> Value of optional type 'PFQuery?' not unwrapped

I add the exclamation mark (!) at the end of this line, which remove the error, is this causing the issue ?

I read Parse documentation and follow some exemples but looks like I'm a bit lost here, any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated, thanks.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:DisplayTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DisplayTableViewCell

    let poeme:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    cell.poemeLabel.text = poeme.objectForKey("content") as? String

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(poeme.createdAt!)

    var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error)->Void in

        if var objects = objects {

            let author:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.userLabel.text = author.username

            println(author.username)

        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` happens in the background, while the main thread still running, so by the time you get the response from parse with the values you need the cell you are trying to return in the function is long gone.

The easiest way to fix it is to fetch all the data you need before hand and safe it in a array and use this array to populate the cell.

Comment: Thanks IcaroNZ for your prompt answer ! If no results is been received yet, is the displayed label would not have been blank or empty too ? The println return : Optional("TheNameOfTheCurrentUser") as many time as number of posts in Parse DB.

Comment: Not necessarily, you are using 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' so the values get populated in some stage and when you reuse the cell the old value still there, because you didn't set to anything new the old value that got populate at some stage is been reused

Comment: ok, thanks for following-up, then if I understand correctly I need to get `let author:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser` out of the `findLover.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` closure, right ?

Comment: Yes and after that use this array to populate the data in the table

Comment: Tried it but with no results, the array was populated then on refresh should have be displayed but label keeps displaying the current logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Finally get it work for Xcode 6.3.2 changes, here is the result :
unwrap and optional seams to be my main problem :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell:DisplayTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! DisplayTableViewCell


    let poeme:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject
    cell.poemeLabel.text = poeme.objectForKey("content") as! String

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd HH:mm"
    cell.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(poeme.createdAt!)

    var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: poeme.objectForKey("user")!.objectId!!)

    findLover.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error)->Void in

        if var objects = objects {

            let author:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.userLabel.text = author.username

            println(author.username)

            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```